# How to make seamless and tiling terrain for export and get the same result , piece of advice please?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I would like to know how can I make a tileable and seamless terrain texture for a large map for my game.
first of all I am not a noob in the concept of tileable texture and seamless too.
but my target is unity , I would like to know some question I ve for you to help me.

this is my first map. (the picture below)

[image]

I think this picture for my map terrain is a sort of dungeon's castle floor as toon concept , by the way , see the yellow lines between the joints or intersections of the plane (4 subdivision , 4 faces inside the plane) .
I consider is not bad , there is not seams , the bricks running flows well.

[image]

Then I would like to know if I am right??? (I put the 2nd face and the 4th face, futher more the first UV space from 0 to 1 ... check this picture above. I think is valid ??

[image]

then the result in Unity is this

[image]

Comment: It may not be the only way to do it but you are getting the result you want. CGMasters has a [tiling textures tutorial](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/tiling-texture-blender-tutorial-coins/) and you can find others on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+tilable+texture) for different ways to do it.

Comment: what about the uv space? further more the first tiling ? for 0 to 1 space ? see the third picture.

Comment: Placing the faces to the side of the other will give the same result as placing them on top of each other. The 0-1 space matches the dimensions of the image and then repeats. So being next to the image doesn't give you 1-2, it is another 0-1 space.

Comment: ah ok, another 0 to 1 space?